# Prove that $(A \subseteq B) \land (A\subseteq C) \Rightarrow A \subseteq (B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that ${{(A\subseteq B)}\cap{(A\subseteq C)}}$$ \Rightarrow A \subseteq (B \cap C)$ 
I want to write a formal proof of this but I have a few doubts: 
(1) Do we have to take into consideration the scenario that the left-hand side of the implication is false? Then the sentence as a whole would be true. 
(2) Is it necessary to write this sentence in terms of propositions and then resort to a bunch of tautologies to prove the right-hand side of the sentence? Can we simply assume that the left-hand side is true and so write $x \in B$, $x \in A$, $x \in C$ and conclude that $x \in B \land x\in C \rightarrow x\in B\cap C$ and $x \in A$ and if the conjunction of two propositions holds, then their implication holds as well?

Comment: No, you can read it as "If the LHS is true (applies or holds) then it follows that the RHS holds". You do not have to care about what happens when the LHS does not hold.

Comment: Note that $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true for $P$ false. So when proving an implication, we only need consider the case that $P$ is true

Comment: Part (2). Unless specifically instructed, you do not usually need  to 'resort to tautologies' (or use 'logic' or equivalent conditions written as statements etc) to prove the claim. So you can proceed as you already suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution to the proof**

Suppose $x \in A$. Then, because $A \subset B$ and $A \subset C$, it follows that $x \in B$ and $x \in C$. Hence, $x \in B \cap C$. This ends the proof.

---

**Logical explanation**

When you have to prove an implication $p \implies q$, it suffices to assume $p$ is true, and then deduce that $q$ is true to show the entire implication is true. You can easily verify this by looking at the truth table of the implication.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write it out. Paraphrased, it reads:

> If $A$ is in $B$ and $A$ is in $C$, then $A$ is in $B$ and $C$.

*NB:* Here $B\cap C=\{x\mid x\in B\text{ and }x\in C\}$.